# Im unable to import/use the cov() fonction from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

Im trying to use the cov() fonction to simplify my covariance code, but im unable to import it, is it because i dont have the right version of numpy or am i writing the wrong thing??? Thanks!

```
liste_revenu_ventes = [1515,6646,13123,65151,11555]
liste_visites_magasin = [123, 554, 1542, 4545, 1244]
covariance_visites_ventes = 0
for i in range(0, len(liste_visites_magasin)) :
    covariance_visites_ventes += (liste_revenu_ventes[i] - moyenne_ventes) * (liste_visites_magasin[i] - moyenne_visites)
covariance_visites_ventes = covariance_visites_ventes / (len(liste_visites_magasin) - 1)
correlation_r = covariance_visites_ventes / (ecart_type_visite * ecart_type_vente) 
print("Le coefficient de corrélation est : ", correlation_r)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the code that you are using and any errors that you are getting. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more info on how to ask a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you just have to import Numpy to use functions from it, `import numpy as np`.
And then if you follow the documentation that you can find [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), you will be able to use the covariance function from Numpy.

Side note: Don't forget to add Numpy to your python environment (`pip install numpy` for example).

Side note 2: Try to don't use french in your variable names next time to be understood by everyone :) + follow the guidelines gave by funie200 next time.

Have a nice day.